# Identify dynamically time periods in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, gaps-and-islands

I'm looking for identify time period in a certain data table.

[image: Click to see data]

This is a table with these data (in BLUE):

- EMPLOYEE: EMPLOYEE NUMBER
- DATE: DATE OF ACTIVITIES
- MOTIF: TYPE OF ACTIVITIES
- DURATION: DURATION

I want to create 3 more column (IN RED):

- FLAG: If Motif = Mala, then = 1 else = 0
- PERIOD: The first identify time period where Type of activities is "MALA". This column must work by Employee number.
- CUMUL: The second is to count number of consecutives days in a period. This column must work by employee number too.

I have no solution for the moment...
Thank you for your help !

**Update: 23/11/2020**
Solution of @GMB works fine, thank a lot

One other question: In case of 2 rows for the same date, i want to:

- If 1 of the 2 rows is MOTIF=MALA i want to keep only this row
- If the 2 rows are MOTF<>MALA i want to keep these 2 rows

Comment: I don't follow.  You say you want two new columns, but your example has three columns.  And the columns are not the same.

Comment: I add some details for comprehension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-island problem. You can use the difference between row numbers to identify the groups, then across and within groups :

```
select employee, date, motif, duration,
    case when motif = 'MALA' then 1 else 0 end as flag,
    dense_rank() over(partition by employee order by rn1 - rn2) period,
    row_number() over(partition by employee, rn1 - rn2 order by date) as cumul
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by employee order by date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by employee, motif order by date) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: Perfect it works fine ! THank you very much :)

Comment: One other question:
In case of 2 rows for the same date, i want to:
- If 1 of the 2 rows is MOTIF=MALA i want to keep only this row
- If the 2 rows are MOTF<>MALA i want to keep these 2 rows